# Yandex Money API (invalid_request)

Tags: python, django, p2p, yandex-money

Пытаюсь организовать на сайте систему платежей p2p между пользователями.

Использую Django и https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-money-sdk-python

Создал приложение в https://sp-money.yandex.ru/myservices/new.xml, получил `client_id`, `code`, ввел `redirect_uri`

Вот сокращенный код:

В первой вьюшке запрашиваю право на  выполнение одноразового платежа на фиксированную сумму.

```
scope = ['account-info payment.to-account("%s").limit(,%s)' % (ym_account, credit)]
auth_url = Wallet.build_obtain_token_url(client_id, redirect_uri, scope)
return redirect(auth_url)
```

Во второй (redirect_uri) вьюшке беру параметр `code`, получаю `access_token` и выполняю операцию:

```
code = request.GET['code']
access_token = Wallet.get_access_token(client_id, code, redirect_uri)
access_token = access_token['access_token']
wallet = Wallet(access_token)

request_options = {
    "pattern_id": "p2p",
    "to": "%s" % ym_account,
    "amount": "%s" % credit,
    "comment": "comment",
    "message": "message",
    "label": "testPayment",
}

request_result = wallet.request_payment(options=request_options)
....
process_payment = wallet.process_payment({"request_id": request_result['request_id'],})
```

далее обрабатываю результат

Проблема в том, что при авторизации приложения, если пользователь авторизован в яндекс, то пользователь получает ошибку:

```
Этому приложению отказано в доступе.
Свяжитесь с его разработчиком и укажите сведения об ошибке (invalid_request)
```

Если же пользователь в момент платежа не авторизован, то переводит на страницу с разрешением доступа приложению
Приложение, которое называет себя «....» запрашивает доступ к вашему кошельку
Вводим логин, пароль. Далее переводит на страницу с запросом доступа:

```
Приложение, которое называет себя «....», просит разрешения:
- видеть информацию о вашем кошельке —
в том числе о балансе, статусе и привязанных картах;
- отправить с вашего счета на счет 123456789 разовый перевод
на сумму N руб.
```

Получаем СМС, вводим, происходит оплата.

Подскажите в чем проблема? Почему когда пользователь аторизован в Yandex происходит ошибка (invalid_request)?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, баг SDK. Мне помогло это

```
auth_url = Wallet.build_obtain_token_url(client_id, redirect_uri, scope) + '&response_type=code'
```